# Mongoose does not send the updated result

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, reactjs

Im trying to add an item to an array and get back the updated model.

I PUT my request like so:

```
addCarToDriver(CarToAdd) {
 const self = this;
    request
       .put('api/drivers/' + this.state.race._id)
       .send({
        car: CarToAdd})
       .end(function(err, res) {
         console.log(res.body);
        self.setState({race: res.body});
       });
}
```

It hits the server here :

```
MyRace.findByIdAndUpdate(
             req.params.myrace_id,
             { $push: { 'cars': req.body.car  } },
             function(er, model) {
             if (er) {
               console.log(err);
               return res.send(err);
              }
              console.log(model);
              return res.json(model);
            });
```

Now in  the request callback I would expect the new updated model to get logged, i.e with the new `Car`. It does not. The "old" version gets logged. However, if i refresh the page the model gets updated with the new car.

Of course I need to setState directly in the callback. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoose 4 [has changed](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2793) `.findAndUpdate` behavior to return the old document by default, and if you want the new updated one you need to pass `{new:true}`, [because that was the actual behavior in MongoDB](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2262)

You can patch the Query to set `options.new=true` to have the old way back:

```
var __setOptions = mongoose.Query.prototype.setOptions;
mongoose.Query.prototype.setOptions = function(options, overwrite) {
  __setOptions.apply(this, arguments);
  this.options['new'] = true;
  return this;
};
```